# Universal tractable problem solver

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

Consider $X$ an $\mathsf{NP}$-complete language e.g. $3-SAT$. I'm looking for an algorithm $A$ for solving $X$ with the following property. Given $M \subset \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace^*$ any set of words s.t. $X$ with promise $M$ is decidable in polynomial time, I require $A$ to decide $X$ with promise $M$ in polynomial time

> Does such $A$ exist?

The motivation for the question comes from Levin search which would satisfy the above condition if we considered the candid search problem instead of the decision problem

Is the answer affected by adding the assumption $M \in \mathsf{P}$?